# How do I fix phpdoc creating unusable filenames

Tags: cruisecontrol, phpdoc, phpundercontrol

I'm on Ubuntu running CruiseControl with phpUnderControl and when phpdoc runs it creates filenames like: db_\ArticleCollections.html

And then when I click the link to show the file I get:

artifacts/ymozend/20120320190002/api/classes/db_/ArticleCollections.html
Invalid File or Directory

which makes sense since the filename is wacky. Looks like a windows path?

So I'm stumped as to where to tweak things to fix this.

In config.xml I tried setting: scp targetseparator="/"
etc...

but to no avail.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

At worst, this sounds like a phpDocumentor bug that I've never experienced myself, even via phpUnderControl usage.  Is it phpDocumentor that is writing odd hyperlinks like that inside the docs that it generated?  Or is it phpUnderControl's webpages that are showing hyperlinks like that?  If the latter, I'd look into pUC and its config... which appears to be where you've started looking.

Comment: I've since found that this is a known recent bug.  I've implemented a workaround by patching the code and running a shell script following the build.  That'll work until they fix the bug.  Thanks...